# How to provide a customized function 'complete' to readline of socat

Tags: readline, socat

Is this possible to provide a customized 'complete' function to the `readline` library that goes inside `socat`? I mean something quicker than recompiling the `readline`, some hook or text file configuration?

```
socat readline EXEC:application
```

In the example above, I want to be able to do tab completion of a set of predefined commands.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you want to do. Is that an example command? What is the predefined set you want to use? Why not use simple shell function that takes arguments?

Comment: Let me exemplify. Suppose the set is {"print", "echo", "compile"}. I want to type "ech"+TAB, and it completes to "echo", then, randomly, I want to type "comp"+TAB and it completes to "compile", and so on...

Comment: I suggest you change the title of this question, to something like:
"How to provide TAB auto-complete on a customized function?", otherwise nobody will find it. I found it purely by accident when I was searching for "socat"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only hack I can think of, would be to make a directory with fake "binaries" using the same names as the list you provide, symlinked to some inert executable script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "This is a fake binary, and should never execute. Please check your path."
exit 0
```

Then make sure your `PATH` is pointing to this directory as the **last one**. Now hitting `TAB` should make your shell interpreter think you're looking for another file or binary.

Comment: Perfect! This is what I was looking for but did not know how to do.